# How to refresh contents of QCombobox in QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview, qcombobox

I have QTableView which has QComboBox in one of the columns. The combobox is displaying data from a vector which get updates when I click a button. 
When I start the application the combobox displays all the items in vector. Now I press  the button (which adds more items to the vector) but the combobox doesn't reflect new data in vector. It still shows old data. I am also emitting dataChanged() once the vector is updated but I don't see any change. data() function does get call in the model which does return all the elements of the vector, but setEditorData doesn't get call in delegate.

Am I missing something.

Thanks,

Dev

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to change items on the drop down list of QComboBox? If so you must update them by hand, because it don't track changes to list of items that was set to it. It would help if you post some code how you set vector to comboBox and how you update it.

Comment: Yes I want to change the items in QComboBox when the vector is update. 
Here is what I do, I have a vector in which I add 3 items when I initialize. In ::data() of the model I return QStringList containing these items. And it shows alright. 
Now I add few more items in the vector when one clicks on the button. I also emit model's dataChanged() just after new items are added in the vector. 
I think I will have to catch that signal in model and update the contents of the combobox. Let me know if there is better way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then you need to do something like this function:

```
void updateComboBox(QComboBox *comboToUpdate, const QStringList & list )
{
    QString curentText = comboToUpdate->currntText();
    comboToUpdate->clear();
    comboToUpdate->insertItems(list);
    comboToUpdate->setCurrentIndex(comboToUpdate->findText(currentText));
}
```

Lines

```
QString currentText = comboToUpdate->currentText();
...
comboToUpdate->setCurrentIndex(comboToUpdate->findText(currentText));
```

are optional and used to don't change currentItem after selection.

Comment: and I have to do this in dataChanged() handler on model?

Comment: You have to that in place you know that vector changed and is best in your opinion. Because I don't know what your code look like, it's hard to mark the best place for that.